# Mudança de sinal de valores em Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, boa noite.

Eu tenho um conjunto de vetores cujas componentes (px, py e pz) estão armazenadas em um Pandas DataFrame. Eu escrevi uma função cujo objetivo mudar o sinal das componentes dos vetores caso a seguinte condição seja observada:

Se o valor de pz for negativo, então todas as componentes (incluindo pz) do vetor devem ser multiplicadas por -1.

Abaixo segue o código que eu tenho tentado até então:

DataFrame de teste:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3),
              index=['vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3', 'vec4', 'vec5'],
              columns=['px', 'py', 'pz'])
```

A função:

```
def change_sign(df):
    for value in df['pz'].values:
        if value >= 0:
            df['px_1'] = df['px']
            df['py_1'] = df['py']
            df['pz_1'] = df['pz']
        else:
            df['px_1'] = -df['px']
            df['py_1'] = -df['py']
            df['pz_1'] = -df['pz']

    return df
```

Aplicação da função:

```
change_sign(df)
```

O problema é que quando aplico a função, as componentes de todos os vetores, mesmo quando pz é positivo, são multiplicadas por -1. Isso somente deveria acontecer quando pz for menor que 0.

Estou empancado, pois não estou sabendo o que estou esquecendo de fazer ou o que estou fazendo de errado.

Estou rodando um ambiente virtual em macOS do Python 3.7.1 (Miniconda 4.5.11), com pandas 0.23.4 e numpy 0.15.4.

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem-vinda.

Obrigadão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[TL;DR]](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-iter-rows)

Elaborei uma função que recebe um dataframe, não o altera e retorna um outro modificado de acordo com o que voce especifica.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ch_sign(df):
    df2 = df.copy()
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        if row['pz'] < 0:
            row['px'] *= -1
            row['py'] *= -1
            row['pz'] *= -1
    return df2

a = np.array([[1, 2, -3], [4, 5, 6], [11, 22, -23], [-33, 44, 55], [77, 88,- 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(a,index = ['vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3', 'vec4', 'vec5'], 
                    columns = ['px', 'py', 'pz'])

print("Vetor Original:", df, sep='\n')
Vetor Original:
      px  py  pz
vec1   1   2  -3
vec2   4   5   6
vec3  11  22 -23
vec4 -33  44  55
vec5  77  88  -1

print("Vetor Modificado:", ch_sign(df), sep='\n')
Vetor Modificado:
      px  py  pz
vec1  -1  -2   3
vec2   4   5   6
vec3 -11 -22  23
vec4 -33  44  55
vec5 -77 -88   1
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-iter-rows)